# How to solve nvidia-smi command stuck and not showing anything?

Tags: linux, server, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

My server do not response to nvidia-smi after I use ctrl+c kill the process running my GPU-training code. 
Before today, when I tap ctrl+c, the process first shows keyboard interrupt and then killed by linux. 
But today, when I use ctrl+c, it response with keyboard interrupt but is not killed. 
After I kill this process with`kill -9 <pid>`, I can not use nvidia-smi anymore and I cant train my code.
How to solve this, please.

Comment: Did you find an answer?